# A separation of list by condition applying

Tags: python

I have a text file that has 6 columns and I want to plot 2 first columns. First of all, I should filter the 6th column to separate values greater than 0.0003 and lower than 0.01 then plotting the rest of the table (the first 2 columns). To elaborate more, first, I want to separate the values of the table by applying a filter on the 6th column, then plotting the remainder of the table.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlibe.pyplot as plt
with open('configuration_883.out', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    near = [float(line.split()[5]) for line in lines]
    x = [float(line.split()[0]) for line in lines]
    y = [float(line.split()[1]) for line in lines]

xx = []
yy = []
for i in range(1,len(x)):
    if all(ii<=1.3 for ii in near):
        xx.append(x[i])
        yy.append(y[i])
print(xx)
print(yy)
plt.plot(xx,yy)
```

Comment: how's your `configuration_883.out` file looks like? Include a sample of your file.

Comment: What errors are you getting with your code?

Comment: maybe read it using `pandas` and it will be easier to filter it.

Comment: if you want to filter by 6th column and later plot only first 2 columns then you should first read all columns and keep in list of rows and later filter it.

Comment: @furas I also have tried to use numpy command rather than `With` opening command. What is your suggestion

Comment: it seems file uses space as separator so you can use `sep="\s+"` and read as CSV - ie. `df = pandas.read_csv('configuration_883.out', sep="\s+", header=None)` - doc [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems file uses space as separator so you could use `pandas` to read it as `CSV` with `sep="\s+"`

I don't have data to test it but it could be

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlibe.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('configuration_883.out', sep="\s+", header=None)

print(df)

selected = df[ (df.loc[:,5] > 0.0003) & (df.loc[:,5] < 0.01) ]

print(selected)

plt.plot(selected[0], selected[1])
```